# react how to replace entire url location instead of pathnames stacking

Tags: reactjs

```
<Link to={`channels/${channel.channel_name}`}> {channel.channel_name}</Link>
```

Let's say the user is watching a video (current url = `'localhost:3000/videos/1'`) and they want to click on the channel's link, when they do I want to send them to `'localhost:3000/channels/Lun'`, but for some reason the links just stack like this `'localhost:3000/videos/1/channels/Lun'`... I treid using the replace keyword but that doesnt work too, any help is appreciated!

Comment: `channels/${channel.channel_name}` is appending the current to next URL. Can you share a more complete code example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Need to change the link like this.

```
<Link to={`/videos/${//route here}`}>
```